# Prevent certain element from reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page that reloads on change of "select" option. This causes to clear all of inputs.
I managed to keep text inputs values unchanged after reload, but there is also a file input(I know that it is impossible to save its value as a variable).
`<input type="file">`
I need it to keep it's value, so user will not need to upload its file again.

My question is: **Is there a way to prevent certain page/form element(file input, in my case) from reloading before the page/form is reloaded?**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: By file upload, do you mean the value of  `<input type="file">`?

Comment: Yes. <input type="file">

Comment: Then the file isn't uploaded until user submits the form. Just save and change the value of the input is fine.

Comment: As far as I know, it is impossible to save/change the value of <input type="file">

Comment: Why cant you change the behaviour of refresh to a simple ajax call?

Comment: Yes. You are right. My bad.

Comment: @ShankarShastri, elements may change, depending on option change. Ajax is used and new values are sent to the page by GET, but the form is cleared(refreshed, adding new elements) after that.

Comment: Get all those elements to browser and Hide those elements.And based on the input show the elements.

Comment: It may work. I'll try that. Thank you!